# Java - adding value in a while loop

Tags: java

this one just is hurting my brain. http://programmingbydoing.com/a/adding-values-in-a-loop.html

> Write a program that gets several integers from the user. Sum up all the integers they give you. Stop looping when they enter a 0. Display the total at the end.

what ive got so far:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("i will add");
    System.out.print("number: ");
    int guess = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("number: ");
    int guess2 = keyboard.nextInt();




    while(guess != 0 && guess2 != 0)
    {   

        int sum = guess + guess2;
        System.out.println("the total so far is " + sum);
        System.out.print("number: ");
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("number: ");
        guess2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("the total so far is " + sum);

    }
    //System.out.println("the total so far is " + (guess + guess2));
}
```

Comment: Is there an actual question here?

Comment: Hint: "Stop looping when they enter a 0" is not the same as "Stop looping when they enter two 0's".

Comment: Also, "get several integers" means get one integer each iteration, rather than get several each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the `int sum` variable outside of the while loop and only have one `guess = keyboard.nextInt()` inside the loop. Add the user's guess to the sum in the loop as well.

Then after the loop output the user's sum.

I.e.:

```
int sum;
while(guess != 0)
{   
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
    sum += guess;
}
System.out.println("Total: " + sum");
```

**Edit:** also remove the `guess2` variable, as you will no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

The code will be as below :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     int input = 0;
     int total = 0;
     System.out.println("Start entering the number");
     while((input=keyboard.nextInt()) != 0)
         {   
             total = input + total;
         }
    System.out.println("The program exist because 0 is entered and sum is "+total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Programming by Doing :)

```
    int x = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("I will add up the numbers you give me.");
    System.out.print("Number: ");
    x = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (x != 0) {
        sum = x + sum;
        System.out.println("The total so far is " + sum + ".");
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        x = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("\nThe total is " + sum + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddingInLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number, total = 0;

        System.out.print("Enter a number\n> ");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();
        total += number;

        while (number != 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter another number\n> ");
            number = keyboard.nextInt();
            total += number;
        }
        System.out.println("The total is " + total + ".");
    }
}
```

You first prompt the user to enter a number. Then you store that number into total (total += number OR total = total + number). Then, if the number entered wasn't 0, the while loop executes. Every time the user enters a nonzero number, that number is stored in total ( the value in total is getting bigger) and the while loops asks for another number. If and when a user enters 0, the while loop breaks and the program displays the value inside total. :D I myself am a beginner and had a bit of an issue with the logic before figuring it out. Happy coding!